# How to open the ports on firewall in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, networking, firewall, iptables

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. I just want to open the most common ports namely

1. FTP (port 20 TCP/UDP)
2. HTTP (port 80 TCP/UDP)
3. SMTP (port 25 TCP)
4. ETC

I've tried all the ways in `iptables`, `ufw`, and `gufw`.

In the end, it still remains unchanged with the same error: 
`Connection refused.`

I can't even access the home page on HTTP port: 80 from the other device.

Comment: We need more information.  What device are you trying to access, where does it reside, and where does the device you're using ot try and access the system that is running Uubntu reside in relation to the Ubuntu system?

Comment: As Thomas W. said we need clarification. You cannot connect from another device? Did you check on your Ubuntu machine, which ports were open (`netstat`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the opinions and suggestions.
Fortunately I've solved my problem.

The problem is because, I didn't assign the policy for the incoming traffic.

- I installed the [fire starter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/firestarter/download) (firewall gui)
- Then, in fire starter GUI, I added the policy in inbound traffic with the allowed ip
  address : 0.0.0.0/0
- Then, I added all the ports that I wanted to open :
  20,21,22,23,25,80,443
- After I clicked on the apply the changes button, I can connect the
  ports from outsides successfully.

Thanks you all, anyway.